# Run LORE-TSR model on colab no module named '_ext'

Tags: google-colaboratory, table-structure

Im trying to run the LORE TSR Model Demo shared in this github repo: https://github.com/AlibabaResearch/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/tree/main/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR.

I followed the Instructions but when I try to run the demo.py script I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/demo.py", line 13, in <module>
    from detectors.detector_factory import detector_factory
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/detectors/detector_factory.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ctdet import CtdetDetector
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/detectors/ctdet.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .base_detector import BaseDetector
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/detectors/base_detector.py", line 10, in <module>
    from models.model import create_model, load_model
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/model.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .networks.pose_dla_dcn import get_pose_net as get_dla_dcn 
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/pose_dla_dcn.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .DCNv2.dcn_v2 import DCN
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/dcn_v2.py", line 12, in <module>
    import _ext as _backend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ext'
```

1. I tried to setup the contained DCNv2 model (custom xtension i think?) which I think is the root of the problem, the error message indicates that the '_ext' module could not be  build
2. I tried to run the commands coa anaconda promot to follow the instrcutions more closely - same errors

```
`rm: cannot remove '*.so': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'build/': No such file or directory
No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda'
running build
running build_ext
building '_ext' extension
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src
creating /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu
Emitting ninja build file /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build.ninja...
Compiling objects...
Allowing ninja to set a default number of workers... (overridable by setting the environment variable MAX_JOBS=N)
[1/4] c++ -MMD -MF /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.o.d -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.cpp -o /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++17
FAILED: /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.o 
c++ -MMD -MF /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.o.d -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.cpp -o /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++17
/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_psroi_pooling_cpu.cpp:18:10: fatal error: TH/TH.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include <TH/TH.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[2/4] c++ -MMD -MF /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.o.d -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.cpp -o /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++17
FAILED: /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.o 
c++ -MMD -MF /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.o.d -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.cpp -o /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++17
/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_cpu.cpp:7:10: fatal error: TH/TH.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <TH/TH.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[3/4] c++ -MMD -MF /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.o.d -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.cpp -o /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++17
FAILED: /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.o 
c++ -MMD -MF /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.o.d -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/TH -I/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c -c /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.cpp -o /content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.o -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++17
/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/src/cpu/dcn_v2_im2col_cpu.cpp:9:10: fatal error: TH/TH.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <TH/TH.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 2100, in _run_ninja_build
    subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/AdvancedLiterateMachinery/DocumentUnderstanding/LORE-TSR/src/lib/models/networks/DCNv2/setup.py", line 55, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 873, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 467, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 493, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 135, in build_extension
    super(build_ext, self).build_extension(ext)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 548, in build_extension
    objects = self.compiler.compile(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 686, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
    _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1774, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
    _run_ninja_build(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 2116, in _run_ninja_build
    raise RuntimeError(message) from e
RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension`
```

Sorry im new to this all and appreciate any ideas and help on this topic!!
Any idea how I can resolve the issue?
If I want to use the ResNet model do I even have to build the DCNv2 model?